# Why are the Möbius transformations the conformal automorphisms of the Riemann sphere in the sense of Riemannian geometry?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, mobius-transformation, riemann-sphere

There are two ways, how one can define a conformal structure on an Riemann surface. Either in terms of a complex structure, or in terms of a Riemannian metric.

I understand, that the Möbius transformations form the set of all holomorphic automorphisms of the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. What I don't understand is, why they can be understood as the (complete) set of conformal automorphisms in the sense of Riemannian geometry. More concretely: I don't see, that they act transitively on the set of conformally equivalent metrics:

[Jost](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-33067-7) defines a conformal Riemannian metric on a Riemann surface in local coordinates as
\begin{equation}
\lambda(z)^2 dz d\bar{z}
\end{equation}
with $\lambda$ being a positive valued, smooth (in the sense of real analysis, I guess) function.

Now consider the Riemann sphere and choose (for simplicity) the metric with $\lambda(z) = 1$ on the Riemann sphere. If we now caluclate the pullback of this metric along a Möbius transformation
\begin{equation}
Z(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}
\end{equation}
with $ad - bc = 1$, then the pullback metric is given by:
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{1 + z \bar{z}}{|az + b|^2 + |cz + d|^2}\right) dz d\bar{z}
\end{equation}
But $\lambda(z)$ was just required to be smooth and positive (i.e. real) valued and of course one should find such functions on the Riemann sphere, which cannot be written as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1 + z \bar{z}}{|az + b|^2 + |cz + d|^2}
\end{equation}

Hence, there are conformal metrics, which cannot be reached by a Möbius transformation from the metric with $\lambda(z) = 1$. I.e.: There are different classes of metrics, which are related by a conformal transformation (in the sense of Riemannian geometry), but not by a Möbius transformation. But now the uniformization theorem tells us, that there is only one equivalence class of conformal structures on the Riemann sphere.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: You are not free to choose $\lambda$ as you please! The definition is that a metric $g$ is conformal, if in local coordinates $g = \lambda(z)^2 dz d\bar z$ for some smooth function $\lambda$. But if you set $\lambda \equiv 1$, this metric is not defined outside your local open set.

Comment: Yes, but I am on the Riemann sphere, and there this function defines the globally defined chordal metric, if I am not mistaking.

Comment: Where did you see the claim that they act transitively on the set of conformal Riemannian metrics? This is simply false.